# Ruby Koans Step 6

Tags: ruby

Can someone explain what is happening between the asterisks?

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/edgecase')

class AboutNil < EdgeCase::Koan
  def test_nil_is_an_object
    assert_equal true, nil.is_a?(Object), "Unlike NULL in other languages"
  end

  def test_you_dont_get_null_pointer_errors_when_calling_methods_on_nil
    # What happens when you call a method that doesn't exist.  The
    # following begin/rescue/end code block captures the exception and
    # make some assertions about it.
    # ****************************************

    begin
      nil.some_method_nil_doesnt_know_about
    rescue Exception => ex
      # What exception has been caught?
      assert_equal NoMethodError, ex.class

      # What message was attached to the exception?
      # (HINT: replace __ with part of the error message.)
      assert_match(/undefined method `some_method_nil_doesnt_know_about' for nil:NilClass/, ex.message)

    # ****************************************
    end
  end
```

Comment: Lines 12 to 22 is not a balanced code chunk. 22 closes the method definition.

Answer (score 1):

The `begin` and `rescue` statements are a way of implementing [exception handling](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_exceptions.htm) in ruby.

> Everything from `begin` to `rescue` is protected. If an exception occurs during the execution of this block of code, control is passed to the block between `rescue` and `end`.

In other words, the code is making sure your program won't break when you call a method that doesn't exist for [`nil`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/NilClass.html).

`nil.some_method_nil_doesnt_know_about` is causing an exception (the exception *should* be [`NoMethodError`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/NoMethodError.html)), therefore the code in the `rescue` block will be executed, instead of the program crashing.

`assert_equal NoMethodError, ex.class` is making sure the exception indeed was `NoMethodError`, and the next line is making sure the error messages match.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thank you for your explanation.

I hope it helps other, too.